# Create a new entity and set field value

Tags: rules

With the Rules module, I collect a list of row (text value) from a view, then iterate the list (variable `list_item`) and add this action:

- Create new entity of type xxxx, (variable `entity_created`);

I add a PHP action that extracts a substring from `list_item`, convert the substring in a Unix timestamp, and set a field "date" of `entity_created`.

The rule create only one entity, and not one entity for each item in `list_item`.

Does anybody know how to create one entity for each item in `list_item`?

Comment: Would you mind to put your answer separately and then check it as solved? it will help other members of the community to identify quickly the solution :D

Comment: Ok. sorry. 15 character minimum.

Comment: ahem... i don't know how to check solved :(

Comment: You can check here, It is said in there: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green. Before and after images: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the one suggested in [Creating Entities in a Rules loop creates one first entity only](http://drupal.org/node/1683062).

After an actions of entity create, or data set, add the "Save entity" Action, and click on the "Force saving immediately" checkbox below on the form. Without selecting the checkbox, the Rules module creates only the first entity.